# Magnetic field in a cylinder with an off-axis hole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Take a long cylinder of radius $ a$.
It has a long cylindrical hole of radius $b$ parallel to the cylinder axis.
The distance between the two axes is $d$. If the cylinder has a uniform current density of $J$, calculate the magnetic field at the centre of the cable, and at the centre of the hole.

I understand this to be a problem involving superposition. I have managed to calculate the magnetic field in the hole to be $ \frac{\mu_0 Jd}{2} $

I am confused how to get the magnetic field at the centre of the cylinder. I thought to calculate the magnetic field of the whole cylinder  without a hole, and the subtract from that my answer for the magnetic field in the hole i.e.:

$B_{net} = B_{cylinder} - B_{hole} $

but this does not give me the answer i expect.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Consider the hole as just another cylinder with opposite current density of the same absolute value which compensates the current density field of the large cylinder within the hole.

When you have understood this concept apply superposition of the B-fields.

One hint: The answer is maybe much simplier than you expect and this is directly related to the cylinder axes and to the B-field of a symmetric circular-cylindrical conductor in dependence of the radius (as distance from the axis).

Comment: This is what I had attempted before.I have calculated the magnetic field in the hole as stated in the question, but am confused about the field in the main cylinder. Is the field in the main cylinder (without a hole) given by $ \mu_0 Ja / 2$?

Comment: No, the field inside of the main cylinder is not constant. Consider a circular path around the axis with radius $\rho<a$. How large is the current enclosed by this path? How long is the path? This gives you the value of $H$ and $B$.

Comment: Current enclosed is given by the product of the current density and the area so $I_{enc} = JA=J\pi \rho^2 $ Path length is just given by $2\pi\rho $? So then apply Ampere's law?

Comment: Yes, so we get $\vec{B}=\frac{1}{2}\mu_0 J\rho\,\vec{e}_\alpha$ inside the single conductor. Only at the boundary you get $\vec{B}=\frac{1}{2}\mu_0 J a\,\vec{e}_\alpha$. Ah yes, and what is the value at $\rho=0$ for a single conductor (i.e. on the axis)?

Comment: So on the axis at $\rho=0$ the path length and magnetic field are both zero?

Comment: On the axis the field is zero because of continuity of $B$. This is all for the single circular cylindrical conductor. Now, you can combine the fields of two such things. Be careful, the field of the hole may be an outer field if $d<b$.

Comment: $d>b$ so we don't need to worry about outer fields.I am confused as to the next step. We want the magnetic field at the centre of the cylinder. This is a superposition of a full cylinder and a smaller cylinder of opposite current density. So the net field at the centre of the cylinder is just the sum of these?

Comment: In general you also have to regard the direction of the field vectors and apply vectorial summation. But, in your special case this is rather simple since one of the fields is zero. It would be a nice excersice to calculate the field also in an off-axis point.